# What should an ARKit app do when the user leaves the current screen?

Tags: ios, arkit

Should the app keep the ARKit session open or pause it while the user leaves the current view controller or app? I've noticed a battery drain when using ARKit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not pause the session when the user leaves the app to the background, as [`sessionWasInterrupted`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionobserver/2891620-sessionwasinterrupted) delegate automatically handles that:

> An interruption is equivalent to manually pausing the session. Do not
>   call **pause()** in response to this callback, as that prevents your app
>   from being notified when the interruption ends.

And if the user stays on your app, but leaves the AR experience section, it depends on what your app does and its logic. You could pause and resume the session, or stop the session, save the [world map](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldmap) and restore the session the next time user enters AR section later (even after terminating the app), just like how it was before the user left, including virtual contents that have been added before, or just start a new session.

ARKit is processor intensive and performs heavy processes on each frame the app is running, so the battery usage is heavy as well.